# How to display row (or index) number on Kendo UI Grid column via template?

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kendo UI Grid Serial number column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270959/kendo-ui-grid-serial-number-column)

I would like to have a Kendo UI Grid column with a row index number. Is it maybe possible using row template?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you give us more details about the behaviour: what happens if you sort, filter... Should be the original order or the new one.

Comment: Interesting point. No sorting necessary for this grid in particular. For now, I would like to know how to have dynamic row numbers in a column, just specifying the line number. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270959/kendo-ui-grid-serial-number-column)